# Why use completableFuture If tasks are dependent

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, completable-future

I am using ExecutorServices very efficiently in my application, which has to deal with order processing, 
now order lifecycle has multiple phases which needs to be completed in sequence. whereas 2 orders should be processed independently to each other.

Sudo code looks like below:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    List<Future<Boolean>> orderStatus = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
        Future<Boolean> status = service.submit(() -> {
            ProcessOrder();
        });
        orderStatus.add(status);
    }

public Boolean ProcessOrder(){
   Order order = PollOrder();
   order =  EnrichOrder(order);
   order =  Payment(order);
   order =  confirmOrder(order);
   return true;
}
```

on the other hand, if i am using CompleteableFuture, the only advantage i am seeing is the use of common forkjoin pool, where code looks simple and much readable, but since the tasks are interdependent in the same order processing what are the practical advantage of using CompleteableFuture when get() is blocking in any case.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
    CompletableFuture<Order> orderStatus= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->pollOrder())
            .thenApply(order -> enrichOrder(order))
            .thenApply(order -> payment(order))
            .thenApply(order -> confirmOrder(order)); 
}
```

Comment: Why does your second example not simply call `..supplyAsync(()->ProcessOrder());`? If `ProcessOrder()` did what you want in the first case, won't it still do what you want in the second case?

Comment: You’re error handling is missing in both cases - that’s somewhere where CF really shines!

Answer (score 2):

I think one advantage is better utilizing thread pools. ExecutorService code sample uses the same pool for every operation. These operations can be IO intensive or computation intensive. Running these operations on different pools will better utilize system resources.(*) It is very easy to run tasks on different pools with async methods of CompletableFuture.

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->comp1()) // start in common-pool
            .thenApplyAsync(order -> io1(order),ioPool) // lets say this is IO operation 
            .thenApplyAsync(order -> comp2(order)) // switch back to common-pool
            .thenApplyAsync(order -> io2(order),ioPool); // another io
```

In this example when comp1 task finishes, io1 task will be executed in IO thread pool and common pool threads can serve other tasks during this time. At the end of io1 task, comp2 task will be submitted to common-pool.

You could achieve the same thing without using CompletableFuture's, but the code will be more complicated. (like passing comp2 task to io1 method as parameter, and submitting it from io1 method to common pool at the end.)

Also when writing async code, I think completableFuture pipeline should be finished with another async call instead of get method.

(*) Let's say this is code working on a 8 core machine, submitting 100 computation task to this pool of 100 thread will not perform better than, running them 8 at a time.